# How to use OSX built in VNC client to connect to localhost with port forwarding

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I already have ssh port forwarding set up, and it works with Chicken of the VNC, host set to 'localhost' and port set to the port I have forwarded.

Soon, I won't be able to use Chicken, because the latest OSX version, Catalina, won't let it run because it is a 32bit app.

I've tried to do the same with Screen Sharing, connecting with `vnc://localhost:XXXX`, but then it asks for a password, which it shouldn't need, and doesn't connect. How can I use the built in VNC client to connect to my remote desktop?

Answer (score 2):

Try [this 64-bit version](https://github.com/boecko/chicken/releases/tag/v2.2b3) of Chicken

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. (I won't accept the answer because it doesn't answer my question, but it does solve the problem, so I'll give you an upvote)